# Instagram API to Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I was using the Instagram API to get the last media from a client's account. But as you know, most of the capabilities are deprecated(retired...) now.
So I tried the Facebook Graph API, but I don't understand how this works...

I tested with my FB account and a test Facebook Page. So I need to link my Facebook account with an Instagram Business account. 
But my problem is, what must I ask my client? I can't ask him his accounts... How am I supposed to do?
Can't I just use my FB account and have permission to get media from another Instagram account?

Thank you!

Comment: No, you need to connect the account to a page first. If you don’t want to ask your client for direct access to their instagram account, then let them connect it to a page of their’s, and grant you administrative access to the page.

Comment: If I got many apps, do I need to create a facebook page per app to have the permissions for each instagram account ?

Comment: What’s that got to do with the number of apps? More than one app can interact with a Facebook page, if that’s what you’re asking ...

Comment: Ok, so if I can use just one FB page for all my apps, how can I link many Instagram accounts to my FB Page ?

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure your question was fixed or not. So this one some step you need to do for using Graph API Instagram

1. You need to create a APP on https://developers.facebook.com/apps/, This app have some permission for get data of Instagram. In **Products** part, You need to register 3 things

   - Instagram (Permission for get media of business account and mention media of @business account)
   - Wedhook (Facebook will return data for new @mention and comment in media of Instagram  account which linked to your app),
   - Facebook Login (for login account and link your Instagram Business Account to your App).

[image]

2. Change Instagram account to business Account, Graph API only accept to get data of a a Business Account and **Mention media of that account**. After changed, You need to link that account to a Page of Facebook (Setting -> Instagram)
   **one Instagram account only connected to a Page**. You can create multi Page to connect an other one

[image]

3. Using Graph Api to link Your Page to Your App.

All of thing you need to do in here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started

Facebook is building this API so I think you need to update for any change logs of them.